# JavaScript Canvas Animation Using SetTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I've been working on a chunk of code for a would-be Sierpinski fractal animation, but for some reason, the animation part just doesn't seem to work. I also tried using setInterval(), with the same results, namely a blank canvas. The idea is to draw an equilateral triangle with vertex coordinates as parameters step by step, as though somebody was drawing it on a piece of paper. Could you have a look to see what's wrong with it?

On a side note, I've copied a few examples of canvas animation off a few web tutorials, and none of them appear to be working in my files either. I use Firefox and Chrome, both up to date, so I guess it's not a technical issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
  canvas {
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: white;
   background-position: center;
   position: relative;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
  }
```

```
<body>

<canvas id="sCanvas"></canvas>

<script>
```

This is where the animation is supposed to take place; draws a line from (Ax,Ay) to (Bx,By).

```
function lineAnimation(x1,y1,x2,y2,ctx) {
  var deltaX = (x2 - x1) / 100;
  var deltaY = (y2 - y1) / 100;
  var x = x1;
  var y = y1;
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x+deltaX,y+deltaY);
    ctx.stroke();
    x += deltaX;
    y += deltaY;
  }, 100);
  if ((x===x2) && (y===y2)) clearTimeout(timer);
}



function drawTriangle(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,ctx) {

    lineAnimation(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,ctx);
    lineAnimation(Bx,By,Cx,Cy,ctx);
    lineAnimation(Cx,Cy,Ax,Ay,ctx);

}

function init() {

  var canvas=document.getElementById("sCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;

  drawTriangle(10,10,30,50,50,10);

}

init();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
function lineAnimation(x1,y1,x2,y2,ctx) {
  var deltaX = (x2 - x1) / 100;
  var deltaY = (y2 - y1) / 100;
  var x = x1;
  var y = y1;
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    var canvas=document.getElementById("sCanvas"); //Added Change
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //Added Change
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x+deltaX,y+deltaY);
    ctx.stroke();
    x += deltaX;
    y += deltaY;
  }, 100);
  if ((x===x2) && (y===y2)) clearTimeout(timer);
}



function drawTriangle(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,ctx) {

    lineAnimation(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,ctx);
    lineAnimation(Bx,By,Cx,Cy,ctx);
    lineAnimation(Cx,Cy,Ax,Ay,ctx);

}

function init() {

  var canvas=document.getElementById("sCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;

  drawTriangle(10,10,30,50,50,10);

}

init();
```

It is giving you an error over  `ctx.moveTo(x,y);` and   `ctx.lineTo(x+deltaX,y+deltaY);` because thet are not able to use you `ctx` which is basically an object of your `canvas`. so  just try to add them in code and things will work fine

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/7Ldr8/25/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are requiring the parameter `ctx` which you didn't include, as such they don't know what `ctx` is. All you need to do is include it in `drawTriangle()`:

```
drawTriangle(10,10,30,50,50,10,ctx);
```

[And then everything works.](http://jsfiddle.net/bff47oLy/)

Comment: Damn. Thanks a lot. Reminds me of that time I was searching for a semicolon for 3 hours.